# how to use javascript to create and aframe entity with animation

Tags: javascript, animation, aframe

syntax please for <animation... and properties when using javascript setAttribute(
I tried obj.setAttribute("animation",value) and  all sort of different values: position, begin, end, nothing works
I can get  animation to work with no problem declaratively but not  programatically i.e.
create.element(a-box with with animation

Answer (score 0):

Share runnable code with your attempt or it will be hard to help. Glitch is a great option [https://glitch.com/~aframe](https://glitch.com/%7Eaframe)